# Is this android vulnerability bug #8219321 fixed?

Tags: root-access, bugs

In 2013, Bluebox Security announced that they had found a bug in Android that could be used to modify the contents of any application package (including ones distributed as part of the system software) without affecting the attached cryptographic signatures; details to be disclosed at Black Hat USA 2013. I don't want to explain in detail as this site explain it well: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2483525/security0/android-flaw-lets-attackers-modify-apps-without-breaking-signatures.html

However there was no news if it has been fixed. I find that there is really an app "Xmodgames" which is exactly doing the same thing.After granting it root permissions It modifies game files without breaking its signature.
You can't update that app automatically from play store once its signature get broken right? I assumed the same thing but even if xmodgames applies the mod on a game you can still update that game from play store. It means that it keeps the signature intact. Has it not really  been fixed till yet?

Comment: The answer is important for me because then  I'll look forward how apps with granted root permissions do that without breaking signature.

Comment: The only way an APK needs to be resigned is if its content gets altered. I don't know about XmodGames, but a similar tool, Lucky Patcher, extracts the file called **classes.dex** (the binary) from the target **base.apk** (signed archive), **performs a check** to determine the bytes to patch, **creates the base.odex** with what's unchanged from the classes.dex and the patch itself (the patched bytes must be located at the same offset as the original ones), and finally **puts the base.odex** into a subdirectory called **arm** where the original base.apk resides, for which root is needed.

Comment: I find that after apk is installed, its classes l.dex file is copied in /data/dalvik-cache folder. Doesn't it require new signature after modifying it?

Comment: The funny thing is that the **DEX** and **ODEX** are not signed: they are executables. Think of them as a sequence of ones and zeroes. The **APK** is somewhat of a ZIP archive, and can archives be signed? Indeed they can. So, resign just the APK if you edit its contents and repack it. Patch the **DEX** and **ODEX** directly, no further operations required. Granted, patching is way harder than decompiling, editing, recompiling and signing.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Do you have any link where I can learn more about dex and odex patching and modification?

Comment: [These](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html) are the Smali instructions references. You should be able to correctly patch a DEX file by binary editing it, and replacing its opcodes, although I suggest you to try decompiling from a computer to familiarize with Smali's workings, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was [fixed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9edf43dfcc35c761d97eb9156ac4254152ddbc55) (sourced from [MasterKeyDualFix](https://github.com/Tungstwenty/MasterKeyDualFix)) on Wed Jul 03rd 2013. Generally vulnerabilities like this are reported to Google a long time prior to it being publicly announced. In this case it was reported to Google in Feb 2013 and the fix had already been passed to OEMs to include in their releases. (Note, the date it was committed to AOSP (the first link) is not the date it was available to Google and the OEMs)

As for the second part of your question I believe XMOD works by modifying the files after the app has been installed which bypasses the signature checks. Although I am not that familiar with XMOD I'm pretty sure that it is not using this vulnerability.

Comment: If I recall correctly, XMOD patches the **classes.dex**, similarly to Lucky Patcher, which creates a patched ODEX, so it's possible to update the app without changing its signature.

Comment: That's why both lucky patcher and xmodgames were removed from play store. This is big vulnerability to android apps. Any app with fully granted root permissions can modify other apps in its environment without breaking the signature.

Comment: @user334283 Sure, but the only thing Google does by removing them, is to bury their heads in the sand, instead of properly counter the vulnerability.